# Inventory Management Calculation on R

Tags: r, datetime

How do I calculate inventory data projection on R?

Let's say I have inventory data:

```
Date, Product, Inventory
1-Jan-2017, A, 30
1-Jan-2017, B, 20
1-Jan-2017, C, 10
```

And sales data:

```
Date, Product, Sales
1-Feb-2017, A, 10
1-Feb-2017, B, 5
1-Mar-2017, A, 3
```

... (till end of the 2017)

And purchasing data

```
Date, Product, QtyPurchased
1-Feb-2017, A, 20
1-Feb-2017, B, 10
1-Feb-2017, C, 5
```

How do I produce a new (forecast inventory snapshot) dataframe on R, such that the dataframe looks like ():

```
Date, Product, Inventory
1-Jan-2017, A, 30
1-Feb-2017, A, 30+20-10 = 40
...
1-Jan-2017, B, 20
1-Feb-2017, B, 20-5+10 = 15
```

(the calculation is meant to explain the logic behind the numbers "15" and "40". They should not be printed in the dataframe)

As long as the calculations are correct, the arrangement of data doesn't matter.

On Excel, it would be using VLOOKUP and pointing to different cell positions (e.g. moving 1 cell to the left/right to take the values for the following month).

But how do I do this on R?

Answer (score 0):

We merge the data sets first.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- full_join(inventory, sales)
dat <- full_join(dat, purchase)
```

We also replace the `Sales` with their negative values. We then convert the date and replace the NA's with 0.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Sales = -Sales) %>%
  gather(transaction, value, -Date, -Product) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%B-%Y")) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(value = replace_na(value, 0))
```

Now, the way the levels are arranged in `transaction` is that `QtyPurchased` came last in every date, we can get the cumulative sum of `value` by date and get the value corresponding to `QtyPurchased` (using the `dplyr::last` function).

```
dat2 %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(value = cumsum(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Date, Product) %>%
  summarise(value = last(value)) %>%
  arrange(Product)

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [3]
#   Date       Product value
#   <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 2017-01-01 A          30
# 2 2017-02-01 A          40
# 3 2017-03-01 A          37
# 4 2017-01-01 B          20
# 5 2017-02-01 B          25
# 6 2017-01-01 C          10
# 7 2017-02-01 C          15
```

---

### Data

```
inventory <- read.table(text = "Date, Product, Inventory
1-Jan-2017, A, 30
1-Jan-2017, B, 20
1-Jan-2017, C, 10", header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = T)
inventory

sales <- read.table(text = "Date, Product, Sales
1-Feb-2017, A, 10
1-Feb-2017, B, 5
1-Mar-2017, A, 3", header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = T)

purchase <- read.table(text = "Date, Product, QtyPurchased
1-Feb-2017, A, 20
1-Feb-2017, B, 10
1-Feb-2017, C, 5", header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = T)
```